# Open source Rails gem for the OpenStack API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openstack

What is the leading open source Rails gem for developing against the OpenStack API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at Fog (https://github.com/fog/fog). Fog provides an abstraction for a bunch of cloud providers, including OpenStack. The documentation is a bit sparse though...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to look on [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) for this kind of question. Here the result for [Openstack search](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=openstack) on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [OpenStack ActiveResource](https://github.com/Unidata-SpA/openstack_activeresource) gem.
It's an OpenStack Ruby (and RoR) bindings implemented on top of ActiveResource that supports
Keystone (admin and public), Nova and Glance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but there's [Aviator](http://aviator.github.io/www/) which puppet-openstacklib [started using recently](https://github.com/stackforge/puppet-openstacklib/commit/612fa7e121c9ddc36a365de3053879e1544b409f).